# Out - usage, meaning

Tags: meaning, word-usage

> Different databases use different naming conventions for variable-length string datatypes. VARCHAR(n) or TEXT(n) are common naming formats for variable-length strings. Figure 3-6 shows variable-length strings on country names (COUNTRY), returning only the names of the countries and no padding **out** to maximum length as for fixed-length strings.

How should I understand **out** in the last sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the correct answers given already it might be worth seeing an example of a **padded out** string, in a database context.

A variable length string, defined as `VARCHAR(10)` and populated with `ITALY` would return a string of length `5` containing the characters `I` `T` `A` `L` `Y`. When treated as an array the variable length string would be `char[5]`

A fixed length string, declared as `CHAR(10)` and populated with `ITALY` would return a string of length 10 containing the characters `I` `T` `A` `L` `Y` `_` `_` `_` `_` `_` (where here on StackEchange  I need to use '_' to denote a space). When treated as an array the fixed length string would be char[10].

With data like `COLUMBIA` the variable length string would be `C` `O` `L` `O` `M` `B` `I` `A` while the fixed length string would be `C` `O` `L` `O` `M` `B` `I` `A` `_` `_`

The fixed length string has been **padded out** with spaces at the end to ensure that it always takes up the defined number, in this case 10, of characters.

Many databases will allow you to use a function such as TRIM(yourString) to remove the **padding** spaces.

In both cases the maximum number of characters is adhered to so `UNITED KINGDOM` would be saved as `U` `N` `I` `T` `E` `D` `_` `K` `I` `N` . `VARCHAR(max)` or similar allows almost any size variable length string to be stored without truncation.

Answer (score 1):

Definition 5 applies:

> [***out***](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/out#English) : *5. To the end; completely.*

It's saying that *VARCHAR* does not require strings to be padded with spaces or extra characters to the end (to the maximum length) because they are variable length.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, it means "to completion". (A fixed-length string would have nulls or blanks filling the remainder of the space.)

Another example of that case of "out": *build out* -- to complete a building project.